# Matching unary signs and parsing math with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, unary-operator

One last Regex problem I need help with. What I am trying to do is be able to parse a math expression, while still having my Regex recognize unary symbols. I am using the following to parse an integer:

```
[\+\-]?[0-9]+
```

Which works fine in these 2 scenarios:

```
myVar = -5
myVar = +5
```

Regex correctly identifies both -5 and +5 as integers. My problem is if I have a scenario like this:

```
myVar = 7-5
```

This, however, gets matched correctly:

```
myVar = 7*-5
```

Now what Regex is doing in the 7-5 scenario is its identifying 2 integers, 7 and -5. In reality, what I want is for it to be able to identify an integer (7), a minus sign (-) and then another integer (5). What Regex pattern do I need to do this?

Thanks in advance. This is .NET Regex, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't the best choice for parsing math expressions. Look at [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) or other more appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem input is limited as follows:

1. A max of 1 binary operator (*, /, +, -)
2. A max of 2 unary operators (+, -)
3. All numbers are integers
4. No whitespace

Then the following regular expression will work:
`(([\+\-]?[\d]+)([\+\-\*\/]))*([\+\-]?[\d]+)`
(Ignore the first group of results.)

If you want to consider spaces, add `\s*` between the parentheticals:
`(([\+\-]?[\d]+)\s*([\+\-\*\/]))*\s*([\+\-]?[\d]+)`

Example input and output (from groups 2-4):
`Input      \2  \3  \4
  -5                -5
  +5                +5
 7-5         7  -    5
 7*-5        7  *   -5
-7*-5       -7  *   -5`

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
  ((\d)+[\+\-\*/])*
```

Then use MatchCollection and Groups to get to the desired result.